# D3 saltos de linea en elemento title

Tags: html, d3.js

Basándome en esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065896/d3-multi-line-tooltip-for-svg-element) en el foro ingles. Pretendía hacer lo mismo pero en mi caso, no hay ningún tipo de salto de linea, ni en IE ni en el resto de navegadores.

En un primer lugar (antes de probar con la solucion de esa pregunta), probe esta solucion

```
ppt.append("svg:title")
.html("<span>AA</span><br/><span>bb</span><br/>")
```

Esta solucion funcionaba correctamente en Chrome y firefox pero en IE no me añadia ningun elemento.

En mi segundo intento probé con esto:

```
titulo = ppt.append("svg:title");
titulo.append("tspan").text("AA");
titulo.append("br");
titulo.append("tspan).text("BB");
```

Pero los navegadores ignoraban el salto de linea por lo que probé con la solución de la pregunta antes mencionada. Pero el autor de la respuesta dice esto.

> This version renders as four lines on Chrome 41, Safari 8, Firefox 37 (OSX Yosemite), and IE11 (Windows 7). Unfortunately it still renders as a single line in IE9-10. If you need multi-line display here I'd suggest your own  rendering based on mouse events.

Lo que viene siendo que no funcionara para IE9 ni IE10, por lo que no me sirve.
Despues de esto he hecho varias pruebas que han acabado haciendo que piense que Internet Explorer es <s>una mierda</s> un navegador complicado para programar y que necesito ayuda de la comunidad para saber como puedo hacerlo.

Otros de mis intentos han sido probar a añadir en el `title` elementos `p`, `span`, otros elementos `title` dentro... Pero nada da resultado

Comment: Segunda pregunta del día en la que alguien aparentemente llega recién a descubrir lo que otros hemos sufrido por muchos años: la incompatibilidad de IE con cualquier estándar existente. Realmente necesitas soportar ese navegador? Según la [documentación](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-ie-support), `Support ended 1/12/16 for Internet Explorer (IE) 10 and older`

Answer (score 0):

Ie9 la gran tortura. Creo que podrias probar haciendo de la primera forma, insertando el html. Pero agregarle una clase css al span y asignarle la propiedad display: block. Esta propiedad hace que se comporte como caja y no permita tener nada al lado de el dentro de su contenedor.
Saludos.

Comment: Ya he probado a hacerlo de esta manera pero creo que es cosa del elemento title que no permite ese tipo de propiedades de estilo.